# erro com caracteres ao decodificar uma variavel vinda do js para o php

Tags: php, javascript, base64, encode

Bom dia, estou um problema que não sei o motivo, tenho um código encodado em base64 e inseri este código em uma variável js, do php para js, funcionou mais perfeito impossível, ai eu passei esta variável js para o php, também funcionou beleza, ele exibe exatamente o código depois de encodar, o problema foi ao decodar

Encodei assim:

```
$encode = base64_encode(salt.hash));
```

Passei para o js assim:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("campo", "<?php echo $encode; ?>");
```

Passei para o PHP assim:

```
$decode_js = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('campo'))</script>";
```

Decodei e exibi assim:

```
echo $decode = base64_decode($decode_js);
```

Neste echo, o que traz é algo muito monstruoso:

Isso:

> MGszbGk5MGlvb2Y0ZWhwdXNkc2JhYWNmOTNlZTUyZTBlNjI0ZmQ0NzNkZjUyYjVlZDE5N2Y0ODM5NTQ0OWZmN2YxZjY0ZDg2ZDgzZWQ0YjBlNmRlNTFiYTk2ZmQ2YjA1ZjU1MjI5MTFmM2Q2OWI5N2RiMGUwMzhlYTg0OWZmYzBjZThiYWQxMDMxZjUzMmRkYWI0NzFiOTAzZA

Virou isso:

> �����hr鞞�+�ץ�ƥJ�+j�z�-zh�>)�����

Alguém consegue me ajudar em algo?
Grato desde já

Comment: Você já viu se o valor do decode_js é exatamente o valor do campo? Porque eu acho que você está decodificando o "<script>" também

Comment: pois é @khaosdoctor também achei isso, e para isso não ocorrer? tem outra forma de passar a variável js para uma variável php? pois se eu decodificar antes, funciona, dos não

Comment: Você não consegue utilizar o javascript dentro do PHP desta forma. O PHP é uma linguagem de servidor, e sua execução é realizada antes de qualquer dado chegar ao browser. Para enviar uma variável para o PHP, pode você enviar um form ou, no caso da não possibilidade de um refresh de página, usar AJAX.

Comment: Acho que o meio seria você criar um cookie... É um dos meios mais simples.

Comment: @KhaosDoctor o problema é justamente, não poder utilizar cookie, o IE trava cookie por padrão, ai esta  problema que me fez pensar neste código ai de cima, ai travei neste ponto

Comment: @brunoapimentel neste caso, eu iria fazer um ajax para passar a variável para o php como se fosse um refresh de pagina com method post no caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está decodando a função do javascript e não a saída do document.write, pois o php envia a informação pro servidor primeiro, para depois executar o javascript. Mantive a saída em javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
$salt_rash = 'seucodigo';
$encode = base64_encode($salt_rash);
?>

function setCodigo() {
   localStorage.getItem('campo', '<?php echo $encode?>');
}

function getCodigo() {
 var codigo = base64_decode_js(localStorage.getItem('campo'));
 document.write(codigo);
}

function base64_decode_js(data) {
 var b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
  var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
    ac = 0,
    dec = '',
    tmp_arr = [];

  if (!data) {
    return data;
  }

  data += '';

  do { // unpack four hexets into three octets using index points in b64
    h1 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
    h2 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
    h3 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
    h4 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));

    bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;

    o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
    o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
    o3 = bits & 0xff;

    if (h3 == 64) {
      tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
    } else if (h4 == 64) {
      tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
    } else {
      tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
    }
  } while (i < data.length);

  dec = tmp_arr.join('');

  return dec.replace(/\0+$/, '');
}
</script>

<body onload="setCodigo();getCodigo();">
```

Comment: entendi, teia que utilizar ajax para pegar com o post né?

Comment: Não é bem isso, olha o que coloquei na resposta.

Comment: aata, entendi, fazer tudo isso e depois dar load no body, vou estudar muito este código, ele e ótimo, grato